# How can I solve ID error when sending request to Epic Fhir Sandbox

Tags: python, hl7-fhir

I'm trying to use the sandbox from https://fhir.epic.com/ for Backend Services.

I am following this tutorial : https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=oauth2&section=BackendOAuth2Guide :

I already register a new app, created a JWT (using SSL keys) tested the JWT on https://jwt.io/ : works fine! When I POST the JWT to the endpoint (https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token) I get an access token.

Using this access token, I can access a single patient Appointment ressource but that's it. I don't understand how to access other Resources like DiagnosticReport, Observations, etc. I added them in the scope of my App of course but still doesn't seems to work.

What am I missing here ?

This is my code where I can access the Appointment resource:

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
from jwt import (
    JWT,
    jwk_from_dict,
    jwk_from_pem,
)
from jwt.utils import get_int_from_datetime
import random
import xmltodict


def main():
    instance = JWT()

    message = {
        # Client ID for non-production
        'iss': 'my_iss_here',
        'sub': 'my_sub_here',
        'aud': 'https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token',
        'jti': f'7777-7777-7777-7777-7777{random.randint(100,1000)}',
        'iat': get_int_from_datetime(datetime.now(timezone.utc)),
        'exp': get_int_from_datetime(datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(minutes=2)),
    }


    # Load a RSA key from a PEM file.
    with open('./privatekey.pem', 'rb') as fh:
        signing_key = jwk_from_pem(fh.read())

    compact_jws = instance.encode(message, signing_key, alg='RS384')

    headers = {}
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

    data = {
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
      'client_assertion_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer',
      'client_assertion': compact_jws
    }
    
    x = requests.post('https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token', headers=headers, data=data)

    access_token = x.json()['access_token']

    headers = {}
    headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {access_token}'
    x = requests.get('https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/STU3/Appointment/eWLhfjXHp4RUczv2om.1Ii2uiHcDc6rMEjO0xHBA3', headers=headers)

    print(x.content)
```

When I change the request for one of these two (of the online tutorial), it doesn't work:

```py
x = requests.get('https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/R4/Observation/erXuFYUfucBZaryVksYEcMg3', headers=headers)
```

I'm using the FHIR ID of Camilia Lopez (test patient). She supposed to have a Observation Ressource but I get an error :

```py
<OperationOutcome xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir"><issue><severity value="fatal" /><code value="not-found" /><details><coding><system value="urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.0.1.7.2.657369" /><code value="59008" /><display value="The FHIR ID provided was not found." /></coding><text value="The FHIR ID provided was not found." /></details><diagnostics value="Invalid FHIR ID provided" /><location value="/f:id" /><expression value="id" /></issue></OperationOutcome>
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those appear to be valid FHIR IDs for the resources requested in the Epic on FHIR sandbox. The IDs in the tutorial are just examples. You should use the test data reference [here](https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=testpatients) for identifying Patient and other resources that are available to test with. You should also ensure you are including [all the necessary headers](https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=oauth2&section=NonOauth_Additional-Required-Headers) in your calls.

Comment: About the headers : they are useful when not using Oauth. Since I'm using it I don't need them. About the FHIR ID you're right, I edited my question with a real test case that does not work.

Comment: erXuFYUfucBZaryVksYEcMg3 is the Patient FHIR ID, not the Observation FHIR ID. If you want to find the Observations for that patient, you need to make a call like https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/R4/Observation?patient=erXuFYUfucBZaryVksYEcMg3. That should provide a response with one or more Observations. Note that you may need to supply additional search parameters, depending on the call type of Observation you are looking for. Example is at https://fhir.epic.com/Specifications?api=999.